# Installed Percona mySQL on CPanel but getting an error

Tags: mysql, percona

I installed Percona mySQL on my fresh CPanel server (no databases yet) according to:
http://www.ecommy.com/linux/install-...el-environment

Everything seemed to be OK and the server also starts fine, except some commands return this error:

```
root@server [/var/lib/mysql]# mysql -A -sN information_schema -e
"select * from user_statistics;"
mysql: unknown variable 'innodb_file_per_table=1'

root@server [/var/lib/mysql]# mysql -A
mysql: unknown variable 'innodb_file_per_table=1'
```

In my /etc/my.cnf I have:

```
[mysql]
innodb_file_per_table=1
userstat_running=1
```

I am planning on using InnoDB for the databases.

Anyone know what the problem is? Or even better, how to fix it?

I have installed Percona 5.5 with yum on CentOS.

Answer (score 4):

```
innodb_file_per_table
```

That setting goes in the `[mysqld]` section not the `[mysql]` section in the /etc/my.cnf. If you move it to the correct section that issue will go away

Comment: I tried that, but when I change mysql to mysqld, the server doesn't start.

Comment: He didn't say rename the section, he said move the variable to the correct section.

Answer (score 1):

Use [innodb_file_per_table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-multiple-tablespaces.html) in the following way under `[mysqld]` section in my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
innodb_file_per_table
```